# TLS 1.3 key update issue on Windows 10

Tags: java, openssl, windows-10, tls1.3

We have a client/server architecture that communicates via TLS. We have Java, Linux and Windows clients and use `SSLSocket` in Java, OpenSSL on Linux and a SSPI based implementation for Windows. Unfortunately I did not find much information for Windows 10 (except that TLS 1.3 can be enabled and should not be used in production yet).

While testing our changes to support TLS 1.3, I see the following issue when one side is Windows and the other side is the Java or OpenSSL implementation, when Java triggers a key update (or we trigger a key update manually in OpenSSL):

Java debug:

```
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2020-07-16 18:28:53.269 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1209|trigger key update
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-07-16 18:28:53.271 CEST|KeyUpdate.java:271|Produced KeyUpdate post-handshake message (
"KeyUpdate": {
  "request_update": update_requested
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-07-16 18:28:53.271 CEST|SSLCipher.java:2020|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 1048576
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-07-16 18:28:53.271 CEST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:241|WRITE: TLS13 handshake, length = 5
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-07-16 18:28:53.271 CEST|SSLCipher.java:2062|Plaintext before ENCRYPTION (
  0000: 18 00 00 01 01 16 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
  0010: 00 00 00 00 00 00                                  ......
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-07-16 18:28:53.272 CEST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:255|Raw write (
  0000: 17 03 03 00 26 49 4C 9F   D7 1F D1 26 8E 32 B7 7F  ....&IL....&.2..
  0010: 5F 8F E2 71 D1 AF 43 D9   E9 06 56 CF 86 71 2A DC  _..q..C...V..q*.
  0020: BF 44 A1 12 83 AC D3 92   EB B1 B7                 .D.........
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-07-16 18:28:53.272 CEST|KeyUpdate.java:323|KeyUpdate: write key updated
```

The data arrives at the Windows side and is put into `DecryptMessage`. It returns `SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN`, but the buffer is changed to

```
16 03 03 00 26   18 00 00 01 01 16 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00
```

which is in fact the decrypted data send by the Java side prefixed with a handshake record header (0x16).

My question is: Is this one of the limitations and not yet fully implemented in Windows?
Or should this already work and I do something wrong? I would expect a SEC_I_RENEGOTIATION return code in such a situation and that I have to put the decrypted data into `InitializeSecurityContext` or `AcceptSecurityContext`.

I tested this on Windows 10 Version 2004 (OS build 19041.330).

Regards,
Andreas

Comment: 0x16 is prefix for handshake 0x03 0x03 correspond to TLS 1.2
0x17 is prefix for application data 0x03 0x03 correspoond to TLSx1.2
Your are probably etablishing a TLSv1.2 connection, wireshark may help you

Comment: As far as I understand, TLS 1.3 is wrapped inside TLS 1.2 packages to avoid issues with old middle boxes.

Comment: you're right (rfc8446) says "TLS version negociation has been deprecated in flavor of a version list in an extension".

Comment: Update: With Windows 11 and after updating the code to use the new SCH_CREDENTIALS struct, key update works on Windows 11. It still does not work on Windows 10 21H2, when it comes to the key update.